# Flutter Global Http Interceptor

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know if it is possible to have a global HTTP interceptor to attach token in header for all requests in Flutter? I've searched a lot and couldn't find any information as where and how to set it up as globally. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is an extension of [Felipe Medeiros's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66536849/8162252) that I could not edit. It is not actually a **global** way to attach a token to every requests, but should be considered nonetheless to create interceptors/middleware.

BaseClient is part of the native [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http/install). You can extend BaseClient and override `send(BaseRequest request)`:

```
class BearerTokenMiddleware extends BaseClient {
  final Future<String> Function() getBearerToken;

  BearerTokenMiddleware({required this.getBearerToken});

  @override
  Future<StreamedResponse> send(BaseRequest request) async {
    request.headers.addAll({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${await getBearerToken()}',
    });

    return request.send();
  }
}
```

When one of your classes needs the http client, inject the `BaseClient` abstraction to the constructor. Exemple:

```
class HTTPTodoGateway implements TodoGateway {
 final BaseClient httpClient;
 HTTPTodoGateway ({required this.httpClient});

 getTodoById(string todoId) {
   httpClient.get(Uri.parse('https://mytodos/$todoId'));
 }
}
```

You can then create a new instance of `HTTPTodoGateway` with an instance of `BearerTokenMiddleware` that will wrap your requests with an authentication bearer header.

Answer (score 7):

You can extend BaseClient and override `send(BaseRequest request)`:

```
class CustomClient extends BaseClient {

  static Map<String, String> _getHeaders() {
    return {
      'Authentication': 'c7fabcDefG04075ec6ce0',
    };
  }

  @override
  Future<StreamedResponse> send(BaseRequest request) async {
    request.headers.addAll(_getHeaders());

    return request.send();
  }

}
```

In the above example the `'Authentication': 'c7fabcDefG04075ec6ce0'` is hardcoded and not encrypted which you should never do.

Answer (score 1):

Using [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package u can do that :

```
Dio dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
 connectTimeout: 30000,
 baseUrl: 'your api',
 responseType: ResponseType.json,
 contentType: ContentType.json.toString(),
))
..interceptors.addAll(
[
  InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (RequestOptions requestOptions) {
    dio.interceptors.requestLock.lock();
    String token = ShareP.sharedPreferences.getString('token');
    if (token != null) {
      dio.options.headers[HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader] =
          'Bearer ' + token;
    }
    dio.interceptors.requestLock.unlock();
    return requestOptions;
  }),
  // other interceptor
 ],
);
```

Comment: Thank you. But where do I put that code? In main.dart file or in every single HTTP request files in my project? Thanks.

Comment: put somewhere u can access this dio instance check out e.g. https://github.com/alibaba/flutter-go

Comment: this is not a global http interceptor but only the http interceptor for this client instance.

Comment: so do u want to create new dio instance each time u hit the api ? just follow flutter-go project by alibaba

Answer (score 1):

Flutter provides [http_interceptor.dart](https://pub.dev/packages/http_interceptor) package.

Sample

```
class LoggingInterceptor implements InterceptorContract {
@override
Future<RequestData> interceptRequest({RequestData data}) async {
 print(data);
 return data;
}

@override
Future<ResponseData> interceptResponse({ResponseData data}) async {
  print(data);
  return data;
}

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with `multipart/form-data` requests or any request that you do using http.send method, so I don't really recommend this library. Better go with @Felipe's answer, no library is needed for this

Comment: this does not work for `client.send` method as well