# How to send a token in a request in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a flutter application, and i have written a server in django. When i send a token to my server for authentication then my server sends me an error of undefined token. Without token all requests works fine, but when i add a token then it gives me an error

```
{detail: Authentication credentials were not provided.}
```

But When i add token in modheader, my server works fine

```
Authorization: Token bff0e7675d6d80bd692f1be811da63e4182e4a5f
```

This is my flutter code

```
   const url = 'MY_API_URL';
        var authorization = 'Token bff0e7675d6d80bd692f1be811da63e4182e4a5f';
        final response = await http.get(
          url,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': authorization,
          }
        );
        final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
        print('responseData');
        print(responseData);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Map<String, String> headers = {
 HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
 HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
 HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Token bff0e7675d6d80bd692f1be811da63e4182e4a5f'
};
```

& use them in request

```
final response = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: headers,
    );
```

Comment: try this answer if u can work with powerful dio package https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745811/flutter-global-http-interceptor/60747270#60747270

Comment: same error, 

check the response from server

 ({detail: Authentication credentials were not provided.})

Comment: what kind of token is this bearer.Something else like authorization/ etc e.g. `HttpHeaders.somethingelse`

Comment: Hey, In my case this is working absolutely fine, Can you please tell me how can I send a request to update the access token, Actually the access token will be reset after an hour so in this case, I want to update the access token programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know to work on your API so I can't tell you the exact answer.

> Check that, Is your backend taking authorization by header or body or
>   I'll suggest you first make authorization by tools like postman then
>   if that succeeds then try to implement that in your app.

Comment: as i said before i am using django. And im using django own authentication function to authenticate my request.
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
and i have read django documentation but could not get a meaningful answer.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

Comment: i have checked a django authentication functions, it accepts in this format ('Authorization': 'Token 4914188f58d7a42183f648a06b1c469fc51b571'), as i am sending in http flutter request. Then what is problem is going on?