# What is difference between Flutter HTTP and Flutter Dio?

Tags: flutter

I have api calls which needs header data and body data.
I found two packages in the pub.dev

https://pub.dev/packages/http --> http
https://pub.dev/packages/dio  --> dio

Which of these packages has better performance and is good to use in flutter apps??

Comment: I'd usually recommend to work with something that is supported by the technology inventor. Even if the dio is more complete, I'd use http as it is supported and developed by dart.dev which makes me confindent in it.

Comment: Dio is a powerful Http client for Dart, which supports Interceptors, Global configuration, FormData, Request Cancellation, File downloading, Timeout etc.

Answer (score 13):

You can use whatever, `dio` is more complete. It depends your need. But the performance are equivalent.

Comment: It would've been useful to know the why of your answer too ;)

Comment: also retrofit works with dio

Comment: @deviant do you have any references to use dio like retrofit?

Answer (score 5):

on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/mzhmnb/http_vs_dio/) people recommend http and i agree with them. it's simple

Comment: how you would implement interceptor with http?

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745811/flutter-global-http-interceptor
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68315016/how-to-use-http-interceptor-in-a-flutter-project