# How to use http interceptor in a flutter project?

Tags: flutter, api, http, interceptor

I have to add header to all my Api's. I was told to use http interceptor for that. But i am not able to understand how to do it as i am new to flutter. Can anyone help me with example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [http_interceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/http_interceptor).
it works as follows,

first you create your interceptor by implementing `InterceptorContract`

```
class MyInterceptor implements InterceptorContract {
  @override
  Future<RequestData> interceptRequest({RequestData data}) async {
    try {
      data.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return data;
  }

  @override
  Future<ResponseData> interceptResponse({ResponseData data}) async => data;
}
```

then create a client and inject this interceptor in it

```
Client _client = InterceptedClient.build(interceptors: [
      MyInterceptor(),
  ]);
```

You can add multiple interceptors to the same client, say you want one to refresh the token, one to add/change headers, so it will be something like this:

```
Client _client = InterceptedClient.build(interceptors: [
      RefreshTokenInterceptor(),
      ContentTypeInterceptor(),
      /// etc
  ]);
```

note that every interceptor must implement the `InterceptorContract`

Now anytime you use this client, the request will be intercepted and headers will be added to it. You can make this client a singleton to use the same instance across the app like this

```
class HttpClient {
Client _client;
static void _initClient() {
    if (_client == null) {
      _client = InterceptedClient.build(
        interceptors: [MyInterceptor()],
      );
    }
  }

  /// implement http request with this client
}
```

Comment: Check my updated answer. I did what you told me to(i guess). Headers are now getting added. Review my code please

Comment: what is the exception ? and you should not add another answer with the same solution. Thank you.

Comment: I have a condition in my code. If statuscode == 200 then parse data else throw Exception("Error thrown");

Comment: run in debugging mode and trace the values, check the request headers, also don't throw an exception if it is not 200, print the response status code and reasonPhrase instead

Comment: statuscode is 500 and when i debugged it response is null. final response = await client.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
        "TENANT": tenant,
        // 'Authorization': 'Bearer ${user.data.token}',
      });   response = null when i debugged it

Comment: how can you know status code is 500 if the response is null ? does the interceptor work? do you see the bearer token in the request ? if yes, please accept the answer and maybe post another question with more details about this error

Comment: It was a mistake on my end. Your answer works perfectly. Thanks for helping

Comment: great to hear that! kindly accept it as the right answer.